# Handle "Overview" button on device skin (emulator)

Tags: android, frame, device, skin

I'm doing a custom device skin, which has 3 soft buttons below the screen. The problem is that when I press the "Overview" button, it shows the menu instead of the "Recent apps" screen because the button name is "soft-left" in the layout file. What is the correct name of the key? I can't find any documentation on this topic anywhere.

here's my layout file:

```
        buttons {
            back {
                    image port-button3.png
                    x 885
                    y 2273
            }
            home {
                    image port-button2.png
                    x 479
                    y 2250
            }
            soft-left {
                    image port-button1.png
                    x 267
                    y 2273
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/blob/master/docs/ANDROID-SKIN-FILES.TXT

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the file but unfortunately it doesn't specify the buttons name or equivalence